# Blank Dashboard Page when logging into WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have tried logging into my wordpress page to add new pages and do other stuff to develop my website but when I login as admin, I keep getting a page with nothing as shown below. I'm not using localhost, we have this site that we are trying to build through wordpress tools.

[image: Blank Dashboard Page on WordPress]

Comment: Look in your servers error log, turn on error reporting, enable WP_DEBUG ... do basic debugging.

Comment: If I'm using Chrome, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

find wp-config.php file and place that
change `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false )` to `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`